# How to prevent UIScrollView to scroll through two pages?

Tags: iphone, ios, uiscrollview, uikit

I have `UIScrollView` and i'm using it in `pagingEnabled` mode. In this `UIScrollView`,i've many images to load.So it's impossible to load all of them. I decided to load five by five. Initially, i load five images and set their position,size and **tags**. So far, i'm able to do this.

Once user arrives fourth page, i need to set sixth page and remove first page from superview. For that, I'm using this method to do that.

```
[[self.scrollView viewWithTag:currentPage-3] removeFromSuperView];
```

To detect page changed event properly, i've used almost all of the delegate methods of  `UIScrollView`, but when users scrolls continuously, i've missed pages. So, i cannot load images properly. For example,when i missed to load page 6, i cannot load page 8.

I tried to disable `userInteraction mode`, even if it's set to **NO**,user can continue scrolling.

What i want to do is,when user did page changed, i want to disable `UIScrollView` to scroll until i finished loading images into `UIScrollView`.

Do you guys have any idea,how can i accomplish that ?

Thank you.

Comment: If you want such a limiting UI, why not just use UISwipeGestureRecognizer to change pages?

Comment: It seems that UIScrollView is more appropriate to use in my case. Because i need to use clipsToTounds property.Also, i don't have enough experience in UISwipeGEstureRecognizer

Comment: UISwipeGestureRecognizer is far more easier to use than PageControl.. All you need to do is handle the animations properly..

Comment: @mstfbsnli there is absolutely no reason why you couldn't use clipsToBounds with any other UIView. UISwipeGestureRecognizer is very easy to use and there are tons of resources both here on SO and elsewhere.

Comment: @FilipRadelic,well, i see why i'm not using UISwipeGestureRecognizer, when i use UIScrollView,the passage between pages is very smooth and looks nice,it's not possible when using UISwipeGestureRecognizer.

Comment: @mstfbsnli UIPanGestureRecognizer then.

Comment: I'm pretty sure `UIPageViewController` handles this behavior 'incremental loading/unloading' behavior for you, and doesn't let the user swipe across 2 pages IIRC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What i want to do is,when user did page changed, i want to disable `UIScrollView` to scroll until i finished loading images into UIScrollView.

If you want to disable scrolling after each page scroll, look to the `UIScrollViewDelegate` methods, like `scrollViewDidScroll:`

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIScrollViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/UIScrollViewDelegate.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/UIScrollViewDelegate

Within `scrollViewDidScroll:` you can set `scrollEnabled` on the `UIScrollView` to `NO`.  Once you're images finish loading, re-enable scrolling through the same property.